# Convert vector data to raster data in GeoTools

Tags: raster, vector, geotools

In my project I am able to open and save shapefile. I want to convert this vector data to image format as a TIFF image.

Please help me the procedure using GeoTools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is a picture of the data then you can simply create an image and pass it's graphic object to the renderer in the same way as you would draw to the screen. However if you want a raster representation of the vector map then you should look at the [VectorToRaster](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geotools/geotools/42c4cc0c3d850b1dea50c07108f171aace35a798/modules/unsupported/process-feature/src/main/java/org/geotools/process/vector/VectorToRasterProcess.java) process.